# Html to pdf with libreoffice headless doesn't show images

Tags: html, pdf, libreoffice

I'm using Libreoffice 6.0 headless and I'm trying to convert html to pdf. The html skeleton of my document is

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <span><img style="height:99px; width:760px;" src="https://mydomain/path-to-image.jpg" alt="Header" /></span>
  </div>
  
  <div style="display:block; width:760px;">
   <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <h2>my title</h2>
    <br/>
    my content ...
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Libreoffice server is a backend server in the architecture, and the image URL is a front end correct URL (it works) but Libreoffice doesn't include the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try it save the image to local. For example on desktop and then try again.

Comment: I printed html and I tried from the server where Libreoffice is installed to wget that image and it doesn't work. So it is a server configuration problem...